# Program to add comments to files and folders

Tags: windows, file-management, note-taking, document-indexing

I'm looking for a program for Windows to manage "library" of files/folders that:

- allows adding text comments to files/folders,
- allows browsing the folders/files so I could read the comments easily.
- Saving comments to plain txt files would be a plus.
- Adding data while appending text to a comment would be a plus.
- Adding tags to files/folders and searching within files/folders managed by the program would be a plus

I found [dmFileNote](http://www.davemorenosoftware.com/index.html) but it costs 15$, I am looking for software specifically at or under $5 (free is best) but open to suggestions.

Comment: Windows has a 'comment' feature for files and folders, but this depends on your version. What Windows version are you asking for?

Comment: I don't have time to finish my search, but Googling 'files folders comments windows 7' turns up things that may be useful.

Comment: Google Drive supports file and folder comments, and its free up to 15gb.  However, trying to find a serious alternative <$15 is going to be hard.  Windows can only tag file formats, folders not at all, that support meta-data.  There is supposedly a way to modify [shellinfo], but it is too long hard and impractical vs $15.